# Converting JSON value into JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to convert a JSON string into a set of array containing the values from the JSON. after `json.stringify(jsonmybe)` and alert it display `[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]` (which i saw as a JSON). I want to get the `noi_user` and `bert_user` and set them into a javascript array. something like `['noi_user','bert_user']` with quotes in each value.

I did the `var stringy = json.parse()` and the alert showing `[object Object]`. and further add this lines

```
for (var i = 0; i < stringy.length; i++) {
    arr.push(stringy[i]['role']);}
```

and the `arr` I get was a value with comma when in alert but the comma missing as i display them in the text field and it becomes a long string like `noi_userbert_user`

What I really want is from `[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]` to `['noi_user','bert_user']`

Comment: as an FYI the quote type (`'` and `"` are identical in JS)  are irrelevant

Comment: If you want JSON (which has different rules about quotes) then `['noi_user','bert_user']` is invalid **JSON**. See https://jsonlint.com/. Be wary of using JSON and JS objects interchangeably, they are not the same thing and have subtly different syntax rules.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use JSON.parse and then reduce to get what you want,

```js
var s = `[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]`

var arr = []
try {
  arr = JSON.parse(s).reduce((acc, val)=>[...acc, val.role], [])
} catch (e){
  console.log("Invalid json")
}
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: but brother, do you know why if i set my text field with the array value, the comma and the `[bracket]` went missing. I am  still getting a long string without any delimited  thing.

Comment: When you set array value to input field value, js will convert array to string by calling it's `toString` method, which will join the array value to make a string.

Comment: Thats right. Thanks brother. and I am using `toString` to convert the array before displaying it into the field control and all went good.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are loking for ? You can map on your array and just extract the `role` attribute of each datum.

```
const jsonString = ...
const data = JSON.parse(jsonString).map(data => data.role);
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```

JSON uses double quotes to delimit strings and field names.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a JSON string like

> '[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]'

You want to convert it to an object, then extract values of "role" fields of each element, put them all into an array.

Your example json string contains an array of user objects within "role" fields. Following code takes this list, loops through each user object and puts role's of each object into a separate array roleList.

```js
    var jsonStr = '[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]';
    
    var userObjList = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
    var roleList = [];
    userObjList.forEach(userObj => {
        roleList.push(userObj.role);
    });
    console.log(roleList);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom function to produce a sort of array_values in PHP but an indented and 2D level like so:

```js
function array_values_indented (input) {
  var tmpArr = []
  for (key in input) {
    tmpArr.push(input[key]['role']);
  }
  return tmpArr
}

var object = JSON.parse('[{"role":"noi_user"},{"role":"bert_user"}]');
var result = array_values_indented(object);
console.log(result);
```